# How to bypass the accept cookies of a website with curl when running the script from a cron on a shared host in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I would like first to thank anyone who reads my question and tries to help or at least takes the time to read it. I searched a lot on google and on other questions asked here but i couldn't get a clear answer or know if it is related to what i am trying to do exactly.
What i am trying to do is: run a cron job script from which i open a google link using curl from a shared host, but the script being stopped with the accept cookies from google. So how can I bypass that ?

here is my curl code:

```
    $useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36';
$timeout= 120;

$url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=world&sxsrf=ALeKk03Q7YEL-UvJX8ODpnmiobrSDNORNg:1624631368943&source=lnms&tbm=nws";


$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)){
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    $link = $content;
    echo $link;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you should need to pass any cookie parameters to the endpoint (Google) you are trying to get with cURL. In which case you should try removing the following parameters from your cURL routine:

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(**FILE**) . '/cookie.txt');

and

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(**FILE**) . '/cookie.txt');

Comment: i dont know why but it worked !!!! Thank you so much ! when i commented what you mentioned it just fired up :D

Comment: There are times when accepting/passing cookies with cURL is useful or required. Even with Google I imagine. But for the task you described, not necessary. Good luck.

Comment: is it possible to explain why it is not necessary ?

Comment: I'll do my best but will also refer you to a brief explanation on cURL's site. Basically the method in which you were setting the cookie option in cURL was erroneous. Should have been "dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_)". Also unless you NEED to receive/post back cookies then you can bypass those options in configuring your cURL routine. See: https://curl.se/docs/http-cookies.html

Comment: Another side note without knowing details of your environment: sInce you are calling the routine via CRON, the user CRON is executing as and the ability to write to the dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_) could be probamatic. But I would need much more information to really know what the issue was exactly. I was just trying to get you a working script as fast as possible - :)

Comment: well hard to understand, so thank you so much !

Comment: Not your fault. cURL has lots of options and I won't pretend to understand all it's nuances. My rule of thumb is to start with base minimum options and then add them to fit the endpoint requirements needed. I.e. be careful of copying/pasting examples and or adding too many detailed parameters up-front.